# Remove bibliography from table of contents beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

So I am doing a presentation and I have a rather long bibliography. I am doing it like this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\bibitem{Numerical Semigroups and Applications}
    \textsc{Assi, A., D'Anna, M., Garc\'ia-S\'anchez, P.A.}: Numerical semigroups and applications. \textit{Springer}, Switzerland, 2016.

\end{thebibliography}
```

But with many more entries. I am also using
`\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]`. The problem is that on the table of contents page, I get this:

[image]

I don't want that ugly Bibliography there. I want a nicer one (formatted as the first two items) or, if not possible, nothing at all. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}` and use a normal section. For long bibliographies you need to use the option `allowframebreaks`:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography} 
  \begin{thebibliography}{10} 
    \bibitem{Numerical Semigroups and Applications}
      \textsc{Assi, A., D'Anna, M., Garc\'ia-S\'anchez, P.A.}: Numerical semigroups and applications. \textit{Springer}, Switzerland, 2016.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I add a tittle to the bibliography slides? There are multiple of them since I have a lot of items

Comment: @kubo - See edit